# Clicking view button and nothing happens

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

After clicking the VIEW button and nothing happening, I started to wonder what's wrong?

```
GALLERIES NAME  POST    EDIT    DELETE  
Slideshow               VIEW     
SERVICES        POST    VIEW
```

Code:

```
<?php foreach ($gallery as $gallery_item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $gallery_item['galleries_name']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php if( $gallery_item['galleries_post_type'] == 'post') { echo "#"; }?>   
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="edit" onclick="location.href = '
                <?php 
                if( $gallery_item['galleries_post_type'] == 'post') {
                    echo site_url('cpages/galleries/'.$gallery_item['galleries_id']); 
                } else {                                
                    echo site_url('cpages/viewpictures/'.$gallery_item['galleries_id']); 
                }
                ?>
            ';">VIEW</button>
        </td>
```

Comment: are concatenating http protocol?

Comment: add `site_url` function definition

Comment: What HTML final code are you getting? Post it.

Comment: right click on the page and choose to view page source, and then check the value of site_url result, may be we can know whats wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use links and describe them as button (role, type, whatsoever) and decore them with CSS. That is:

```
<?php

$id = $gallery_item['galleries_id']);

?>

<td>
    <?php if ($gallery_item['galleries_post_type'] === 'post'): ?>
        <a href="<?= site_url('cpages/galleries/'.$id); ?>" class="edit">
    <?php elseif (): ?>
        <a href="<?= site_url('cpages/viewpictures/'.$id); ?>" class="edit">
    <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

By searching for a better solution, I found an [answer from BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link) that, I think, should solve your problem and help you understand how/what/when questions about buttons, links and so one.